# How to add many controls to a Windows Forms Tab?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, controls, tabs

so i've been searching the net, and I've found some code to add controls to a tab, but I need to add many controls to the  new tab.

Here is what I've got:
A new player tab, that acesses the database and adds a new player, with all the data.
4 Player tabs, with a combobox in the bottom, on FormLoad or a new player is created, this box is updated with all the current palyers in the database, upon selecting one, all his data is displyed.

What I want to do is remove the 4 tabs and add a button on the new player tab, with a combobox to select players and a button to confirm, when the button is pressed, it should generate a new tab, exactly like the 4 old ones.

there is by any chance a way to hide from the user one of the old 4 tabs and every time I create a new one, copy all controls from the hidden one?

Edit: where is the code I've found for adding controls:

```
    Button button1 = new Button();

    button1.Location = new Point(20, 10);
    button1.Text = "Click Me";

    tabPage1.Controls.Add(button1)
```

but what i want is like:

```
new tab tabx = sampletab
tabcontrol.tabs.add(tabx);
```

But this only copies the title, not the controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably would create a `UserControl` handling a single player's data. Then you only have to add a single control to each new tab.

Comment: Yes, a `UserControl` is the right solution. There's no easy way to "hide" a tab page in a `TabControl`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem just right.
Now, going to add database searc to the user control...